# How can i get data of start with 4 and 6 by MySQL command

Tags: mysql

I tried this command to get data which response start with 4 and 6 but giving an error as

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OR '2021-01-27 22:06:00.0' order by START_TIME desc' at line 1

```
select * 
  from AFI_CDR_TABLE 
 where RESPONSE like '4%' 
    or RESPONSE like '6%' 
   and START_TIME between '2021-01-27 22:01:00.0' and '2021-01-27 22:06:00.0' 
 order 
    by START_TIME desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the query that generated the error message. The error says you used `or` instead of `and` in  your `between`. Also use parentheses

```
select * 
from AFI_CDR_TABLE 
where (RESPONSE like '4%' or RESPONSE like '6%')
  and START_TIME between '2021-01-27 22:01:00' and '2021-01-27 22:06:00' 
order by START_TIME desc;
```